# How to send sonar analysis result to a gitlab merge request in Jenkins pipeline

Tags: jenkins, groovy, sonarqube, gitlab, jenkins-pipeline

I have a Jenkins job that runs every time a merge request is made to a gitlab project. The job type is pipeline, I'm using pipeline script from SCM.

How can I send the sonar analysis as feedback to the gitlab merge request?

How can I prevent the code to be merged until the feedback is received from sonar?

Here is the script I'm using:

```
pipeline {
    agent any
    options {
        gitLabConnection('my_connection')
        gitlabBuilds(builds: ["SonarQube"])
    }
    tools {
        maven 'maven'
        jdk 'jdk8'
    }

    stages {
        stage('SonarQube') {

            steps {
                gitlabCommitStatus("SonarQube") {
                    withSonarQubeEnv('my_sonar') {
                        sh "mvn sonar: sonar" // here I want to send the sonar analysis as feedback to the gitlab merge request.
                    }
                }
            }

        }

    }

}
```

The script above just sends pass or fail.

Comment: Did you find the solution? :)

Comment: @PeterS. Unfortunately no.